# edit key->value in .exe.config in SmartClient

Tags: app-config, smartclient

I'll start here: I know nothing about SmartClient, .Net, DotNetNuke, etc etc. This is a "see if alison can help" project for a client's app/ site developed 6 years ago by a company that won't help. I'm just a front-end developer- I've googled all I can. If I don't understand the advice given here, I'm passing on assisting the client. Just thought I would give it a whirl. Here goes:

We simply need to change a key -> value in the configuration of their desktop app which connects to a web service (ASEPublisher). I have FTP and SQL Server access, but that's it.

The desktop app folder contains the following files:

- DataPublisher.exe
- DataPublisher.exe.config
- DataPublisher.pdb
- OleDBDataAccess.dll
- OleDbDataAccess.pdb

Their website contains a folder called "smartclient" that contains the same files.

I just need to change all of the urls in the code below and have the application update to use the new urls. Obviously just changing this file on the desktop and restarting the app didn't do it. So, here I am. I hope this isn't too vague. If you need more info, I can try to provide it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
         <section name="DataPublisher.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
   <appSettings>

      <add key="DefaultFilePath"    value="I:\Staff\fakefolder\database\SA Data.mdb" />
      <add key="DefaultASEFilePath" value="I:\Staff\fakefolder\database\SA Data.mdb" />

      <add key="CNN" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" />

      <add key="WebSvcUrl"    value="http://www.fakedomain.org/admin/ClassPublisher.asmx" />
      <add key="ASEWebSvcUrl" value="http://www.fakedomain.org/admin/ASEWebService.asmx" />

   </appSettings>
   <applicationSettings>
      <DataPublisher.Properties.Settings>
         <setting name="DataPublisher_ClassPublisherWS_ClassPublisher"
        serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://www.fakedomain.org/admin/ClassPublisher.asmx</value>
         </setting>
         <setting name="DataPublisher_ASEPublisherWS_ASEWebService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://www.fakedomain.org/admin/ASEWebService.asmx</value>
         </setting>
      </DataPublisher.Properties.Settings>
   </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```